# Множественный вывод в SQL

Tags: oracle, запрос, plsql, sql

Уважаемые коллеги, добрый день!

Прошу помощи.

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
tabone:
uid     val    
------------
001    val1
002    val2

tabtwo:
t1uid    param1    param2    param_n
--------------------------------------
001      p_val1    p_val2     p_val3
001      p_val4    p_val5     p_val6
002      p_val1    p_val2     p_val3
002      p_val4    p_val5     p_val6
```

То есть для tabone.uid в tabtwo есть n количество t1uid. Необходимо сформировать отчет подобного формата (SQL Dev -> xlsx):

```
001  p_val1 p_val2 p_val3
     p_val4 p_val5 p_val6
002  p_val1 p_val2 p_val3
     p_val4 p_val5 p_val6
...
nnn  nnnnnn nnnnnn nnnnnn
```

Возможен ли такой select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой select возможен. Есть даже [задачка на этот счет](http://www.sql-ex.ru/exercises/index.php?act=learn&LN=65).
Не её вы имеете в виду? :-)

Comment: Да.) Количество t1uid неизвестно и может быть null.  
Подскажите, как такой select построить?   
Я так понимаю, тут надо применить что-то вроде SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH()?

Comment: К этой задаче даны ссылки на соответствующие темы из учебника.

Comment: Да разобрался, спасибо!